# How'd I properly ampersand separate query string array param and format the URL along with it?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

My code's causing some strange behavior and I'm not sure why.

For some reason, the `http_build_query($valuesArr, '', '&');` line isn't separating with `&` and instead it's separating with `%`.

```
$values = $request->get('allValues');

$valuesArr = [
    'valueOne' => $values,
    'valueTwo' => $values
];

http_build_query($valuesArr, '', ','); // separating with `%` instead of `,`

$queryParams = ['allValues' => (object) $valuesArr]; // cast array to object

dd($queryParams);
```

Whenever I do `dd($queryParams);`, the result is (it's also missing the `,` to separate `valueOne` and `valueTwo` for some reason):

```
^ array:2 [
  {
     "valueOne" => "0684857340;0684857340429"
     "valueTwo" => "0684857340;0684857340429"
  }
]
```

How can I make it so that it looks like:

```
^ array:2 [
  {
      "valueOne" => "0684857340",
      "valueTwo" => "0684857340429"
  }
]
```

and the final url looks like (and optionally allow one value passed as well):

`mySite.test/api?value=0684857340&0684857340429`

Output of `dd($request->get('allValues'));`:

```
0684857340&0684857340429
```

Comment: Can you post the original value? What does `dd($request->get('isbns'))` looks like?

Comment: @IGP sorry, that was the old request name, I've changed it to `allValues`.  I've also posted the `dd($request->get('allValues'));` output.

Comment: If this format (`number` `&` `number`) remains the same, you could use `array_combine(keysArray, valuesArray)` to create the array you need to pass on to `http_build_query`.  `$queryArr = array_combine(['valueOne', 'valueTwo'], explode('&', $values));` `$query = http_build_query($queryArr);`

Comment: @sp92 what is `$request->get('allValues')` value?

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always the same (`number` `&` `number`), then this should work.

```
$values = $request->get('allValues');
// string '0684857340&0684857340429'

$keysArray = ['valueOne', 'valueTwo'];
$valuesArray = explode('&', $values);
// array ['0684857340', '0684857340429']

$queryArray = array_combine($keysArray, $valuesArray);
// array ['valueOne' => '0684857340', 'valueTwo' => '0684857340429']

$query = http_build_query($queryArray);
// string 'valueOne=0684857340&valueTwo=0684857340429'
```

If you don't know how many numbers you'll get (`number` or `number` `&` `number` `&` `number`....), then maybe using an array would be better.

```
$values = $request->get('allValues');
// string '0684857340&0684857340429'

$valuesArray = explode('&', $values);
// array ['0684857340', '0684857340429']

$queryArray = ['values' => $valuesArray];
// array ['values' => [...]]

$query = http_build_query($queryArray);
// string  'values%5B0%5D=number1&values%5B1%5D=number2&values%5B2%5D=...'
// decoded 'values[0]=number1&values[1]=number2....
```

Comment: If you wanted that result then simply using `http_build_query(['allValues' => $request->get('allValues')])` should work. It's returning the same query string the request has.